# How to page reload still has value shown on select?

Tags: vue.js

I have a status select :

```
<label>Status:</label>
<v-select
  :options="options"
  v-model="status"
  @input="changeValueStatus"
/>

data() {
 return {
  options: [
    { label: 'Success', value: 1 },
    { label: 'Fail', value: 2 },
    { label: 'Not start', value: 3 },
  ]
 }
}

methods: {
  changeValueStatus() {
     console(this.status)
  }
}
```

Now i want. When i select the status value, and i reload the page the value is still on select.Give me ideas. Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use [localstorage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage) for that:

```html
<label>Status:</label>
<v-select
  :options="options"
  v-model="status"
  @input="changeValueStatus"
/>
```

```js
data() {
 return {
  status: JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('status')),
  options: [
    { label: 'Success', value: 1 },
    { label: 'Fail', value: 2 },
    { label: 'Not start', value: 3 },
  ]
 }
},

methods: {
  changeValueStatus() {
    console.log(this.status)
    localStorage.setItem('status', JSON.stringify(this.status))
  }
}
```

If you want to improve the solution, you could check that `localStorage.getItem('status')` is a valid json object.